# Can we run training and validation on separate GPUs using tensorflow object detection API running on tensorflow 1.12?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have two Nvidia Titan X cards on my machine and want to finetune COCO pretrained Inception V2 model on a single specific class. I have created the train/val tfrecords and changed the config to run the tensorflow object detection training pipeline.

I am able to start the training but it hangs (without any OOM) whenever it tries to evaluate a checkpoint. Currently it is using only GPU 0 with other resource parameters (like RAM, CPU, IO etc) in normal range. So I am guessing that GPU is the bottleneck. I wanted to try splitting training and validation on separate GPUs and see if it works.

I tried to look for a place where I could do something like setting "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES" differently for both the processes but unfortunately the latest tensorflow object detection API code (using tensorflow 1.12) makes it very difficult to do so. I am also unable to verify my assumption about training and validation running in same process as my machine hangs. Could someone please suggest where to look for to solve it?